# $(element).width() reports differently values on Safari mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this script to get the total width of a horizontal div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.portfolio li').each(function(index) {
       totalWidthPortfolio += parseInt($(this).width(), 10) + 12;
   });

   $('.portfolio').css({
       'width' : totalWidthPortfolio ,
       'visibility' : 'visible'
   });
});
```

The problem is on desktop, the script returned 23406 and on mobile (Safari and Chrome), returned 22522.

I also tried `outerWidth(true)` but the result is the same.

Here is the CSS:

```
.portfolio{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    visibility: hidden;
}

li{
    float: left;
    padding-right: 12px;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

li img{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The problems occurs only on portrait mode

Comment: Depends on the styles, contents involved. Can't decide until you post the full code.

Comment: Please show html & css. Likely your `li`s are shrinking slightly to fit the viewport.

Comment: Could also be affected by different media styles for different devices applying padding or margins. Can you check the actual width of the element with a browser console?

Comment: Per your update, where is `total` defined?

Answer (score 0):

The value returned depends from how the browser parse yours li element. 
Try to add display: block properties on css

Comment: I add display:block in all elements, but the error persist.